# Changing the SRC of an image depending on the selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, src, srcset

I have to change the atribute "src" of multiple images with different  items.

So I'm trying to do it with this code:

script

```
function ColorSrcSet(ImageId) {
  var imgID = document.getElementById(ImageId);
  var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
  imgID.src = optionValue;
}
```

html

```
  <select onchange="ColorSrcSet('img-1');">
    <option value="../img/1.png">Amarillo</option>
    <option value="../img/2.png">Naranja</option>
    <option value="../img/3.png"></option>
  </select>

  <img id="img-1" src="../img/transparent.png"></img>
```

It gives me an error and set the "SRC" as undefined.

¿Do anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: `var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");` the `<select>` element doesn't have a `value` attribute, though it does have a value property, which you could retrieve with: `$(this).val()` or `this.value`.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica Except no explicit `this` in inline `onXXX` function calls

Comment: I tried to do it with:

`function ColorSrcSet(ImageId) {
  var imgID = document.getElementById(ImageId);
  var optionValue = $(this).val();
  imgID.src = optionValue;
}`
But it does nothing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no explicit `this` in an onchange function

You can pass the value as another argument though

JS

```
function ColorSrcSet(ImageId, selectVal) {
   document.getElementById(ImageId).src = selectVal;     
}
```

HTML

```
<select onchange="ColorSrcSet('img-1', this.value);">
```

Comment: Ty very much ^^

It works perfectly. You guys are awesome :)